# Sending Notification to Actual caller.

Tags: c++, c++11, singleton

I have an API **currentFuelPrice()** and this api is **singleton** supported.
In my code i made singleton. Lets say Two caller A1 and A2  is added as observer.
Now when A1 calls on **CurrentFuelPrice(). oncurrentFuelPrice()** is received.
Since it is singleton it will send a NotifyFuelCurrentPrice to both caller A1 and A2.
How can i notfiy to actual caller ie. **A1** only.

Below is my code.

```
//single ton
FuelService* FuelService::Create() {
  return (!m_instanceSingleton) ?
        m_instanceSingleton = new FuelService() : 
        m_instanceSingleton;
}

//Register to service 
FuelService::FuelService()
    : FuelProxy(),
      Listener(Listener_path)
 {
  registerListener((IOnFuel*)this);
  fuel_obj = FuelProxy::getInstance();
}

FuelService::~FuelService() {}

// adding observer
void FuelService::AddObserver(
    FuelProxy::FuelNotification* observer) {
  observer.push_back(observer);
}

// calling the API
void FuelService::CurrentFuelPrice(const uint32_t& sessionId) {
  fuel_obj->currentFuelPrice(sessionId);
}

// Getting response send back to caller
void FuelService::oncurrentFuelPrice(const uint32_t& sessionId,const uint32_t&price) {
    std::vector<FuelNotification*>::iterator it = observer.begin();
  for (; it != observer.end(); ++it)
    (*it)->NotifyFuelCurrentPrice(price);
}
```

Comment: WHY do you want to notify the actual caller only? 1. The sense of such signals, (or notifiers or callbacks) is that _any_ registered receiver gets notified. 2. The caller is the only one "who knows" about that change even without notification. However, if you introduce some kind of flag in the caller (e.g. as member variable) you may set it before call of `CurrentFuelPrice()` and reset it afterwards. Then, you can check this flag in the `oncurrentFuelPrice()`. If it's set, the resp. instance was the caller otherwise it wasn't. (_a flag_ - I mean a `bool` variable)

Comment: WHY do you want to notify the actual caller only? ANS==>Because actual caller only needs the data and perform on it.

Comment: @Scheff You mean if there are 10 caller i need to maintain 10 different flag? Can you please elaborate?

Comment: I was assuming that "caller" is some kind of object of a class - hence, my suggestion to make flag a member variable. May be, I didn't get your concept fully...

Comment: Instead of registering observers globally, pass one down to `CurrentFuelPrice`. Have the service track the observer as part of the session.

Comment: But why does the caller not just presume the value is set, why does it need to be notified? [is there a delay/async?] Perhaps the caller could register an additional notification handler just before setting the value, and for that specific handler to deal with the "yes it worked" scenario, then unregister itself.

Comment: @GemTaylor This is Async call hence  The API currentFuelPrice() support this way only.

Comment: So you want to confirm the value has been processed? Then 2 ways. One way is to hold an "expected price" in the callback. If the callback receives the new price == expected price then it can register the confirmation. The other way I mentioned before, register an additional callback, which unregisters after it has been triggered.